# Please use [modern-ui] instead of [metro] for the moment, Metro conflicts

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, retagging

Please use Modern UI for the moment, because Metro was a code name that  conflicts with [Metro AG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_AG).

Feel free to update questions with the new naming as you go around making our Windows 8 part of the site awesome and geared up towards the first weeks in the Windows 8 era...

Consider to use [modern-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) to denote questions specific to applications in the new UI, we can always decide to drop the tag later but for now it helps differ between things like "Skype on the desktop or Skype in the Modern UI?"

**Tag request:** Synonyms from [metro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/metro) and [metro-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/metro-ui) to [modern-ui](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/modern-ui) might be handy.

Comment: I'd like to wait for a few weeks to see whether that name is actually final. And introducing `modern-ui` now just creates yet another tag for the same thing.

Comment: Whether Microsoft likes it or not, I think that people are still going to call it metro.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, they are changing it on all their sites. It is no longer a code name and hence final. Thus that will be the final tag.

Comment: @KronoS: Only devs and previewers, the majority will adapt the new name. And as a major site we must comform to Microsofts naming guidelines, using Metro is actually a trademark infringement.

Comment: It appears that it doesn't have a name anymore, it's just Windows 8 now. [Source](http://www.neowin.net/news/from-the-forums-microsoft-whats-metro-called-then)

Comment: I don't see any official Microsoft source in that article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A synonym appears to have been made, we can always rename it if it appears invalid.

Comment: I did that. Sorry, forgot to update the meta post here.